# in keycloak how to just response with status code than redirect to login page

Tags: node.js, keycloak

Is there a way to prevent the keycloak redirect to login page and instead response with the custom status code? 
I am using nodejs and I want to response back with an error rather than redirecting to the login the login page when the token is expired.
I am doing something like this :

```
app.post('*', keycloak.protect(protect),handlePost);

function protect(token, request) {
  return !token.isExpired();
}
```

I was hoping to campture the event inside the protect function, but the function is not called when the session is expired. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer if anyone else has the same issue:

I just added

```
Keycloak.prototype.redirectToLogin = function(req) {
  return false;
};
```